# Contents of database not displaying

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

I'm trying to display the contents of my database on to the webpage using jsp 
It shows up blank except the html parts of the code like headers "id name " etc.
I think my code is right.Please help

I have tried same codes from many websites.unfortunately all of them end up the same way

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>



<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%
    String host="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname";
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stat=null;
    ResultSet res=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try{
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection(host,"root","password");
    stat=conn.createStatement();
    String data="select * from emp";
    res=stat.executeQuery(data);
    while(res.next())
    {%>
    <tr>
    <td><%=res.getInt(1) %></td>
    <td><%=res.getString("name") %></td>
    <td><%=res.getString("email") %></td>
    <td><%=res.getString("phone") %></td>
    <td><%=res.getString("address") %></td>

    </tr>

    <% 
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>



</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Only the headers (or) the table names in the html part of the code shows up on the webpage

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: There seems to be a java ClassNotFoundException for the jdbc connection to mysql,but the same code executes fine when i try to get the output in eclipse on the console(but doesn't work in JSP)..Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score -1):

No you cannot do it with this code . you have to go for JSTL . in jstl you can do this.

Comment: You actually can do it this way, it is just not recommended.

Comment: The requirement is that it should be in JSP

Comment: Jstl tags are used in jsp.

Comment: Plus you can use sql tags in jsp .